# dynamically fill a ChoiceBox with HashMapKeys

Tags: java, oracle, javafx, scenebuilder

im literally close to desperation here.

Im about to write a little javatool for myself. This tool scans a .txt file for some Keywords and puts them into a hashmap, where "Key" and "Value" can be printed seperately. This is basically working fine. 
Now i want to use a gui (because other people will use the tool also) where the Hash-Key is shown in a ChoiceBox. The problem: the .txt file will be changing dynamically. So i cant just add the keywords. I need the programm to do it dynamically too. 
When im starting my tool everything i got yet is working fine, except the ChoiceBox which seems to stay empty if i dont add the strings previously. 
I figured out that the problem lays in the method how the Choicebox is initialized. I have a "public void initialize()" method which seems to initialize the Choicebox on program's start. Btw: the .txt file is firstly choosed over a "FileChooser" when the gui is open, not together with the program's start.
Someone has a solution for me?

```
private static LinkedHashMap<String, String> stringMap = new 
LinkedHashMap<String, String>(); //declared globaly to use it easier on 
demand

@FXML
private ChoiceBox<String> anschreiben;  //choiceBox filled with "UIText"

public static ArrayList<String> liste = new ArrayList<String>(); //ArrayList 
                                                                // filled with the Hashkeys ("UIText"-Items)


@FXML
public void initialize(){ //Initializer @ChoiceBox
liste.add("Item1"); //if I add it like this, its working fine
liste.add("Item2");
liste.add("Item3");
ObservableList<String> anschreiben2 = 
FXCollections.observableArrayList(liste);
anschreiben.setItems(anschreiben2); //call the ChoiceBox and give the   
                                    //ArrayList as a parameter
} 

/*
* Some unimportant working code to set the gui and the fileChooser
*
*/

public static void readFile (String filepath) throws Exception{

/*
* Code which is working 
*
*/
//Method to print the HashKeys in the console(Just for checkup) and to 
//actually add the hashkeys to the arraylist which should setup the choicebox

Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> it = stringMap.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, String> pair = it.next();

        // The pair.getKey() -> UI Text
        // The pair.getValue() -> PDF Text

        UIText  = pair.getKey();
        PDFText = pair.getValue();
        liste.add(UIText);  //Here i want to fill my ArrayList with my Hash-
 keys which seems not to work together with the choiceBox

   }
 }
```

Comment: I see you left a lot of code out. It's hard to follow your code.

Comment: I am guessing here: Try changing the scope of your `ObservableList`. Make `ObservableList<String> anschreiben2;` global.

Comment: hey guys, thanks for reply. I already figured it out.

I just set a "readFile()"-Funcion Call in the "initialize()" function. So when the program is starting, the file will be read together with it. 
It's of course only working if the filepath to the .txt-file is static. So i will set up a little installation on the final program.